# JPA update doesn't work in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, updates

I have 3 tables:

- `customer(idCustomer,...)`
- `is_managed(idCustomer,idPerson)`
- `sales_person(idPerson,...)`

There is a `@ManyToMany` relation between `customer` and `sales_person`.

When I perform a delete, then it works fine: the `customer`, `is_managed` and `sales_person` are deleted.

But when I perform an update, then the `customer` and `is_managed` are updated, but the `sales_person` not.

For example, if I update a `customer` by deleting the `sales_person`, it's deleted in `is_managed` table, but not in `sales_person` table.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Here's the relevant code:

```
// update customer
public String updateCustomer(Customer customer,ArrayList<Sales_person> sales_persons,ArrayList<Involved_group_relation> involved_groups, Macro_market macro_market)throws IOException {

   // insert the sales_person attached to the customer
   ArrayList<Sales_person> sales_personC = new ArrayList<Sales_person>();
   sales_personC.addAll(sales_persons);

    customer.setSalesPersons_BelongTo(sales_personC); // insert in customer the sales_persons

    em.merge(customer);
    return customer.getNameCustomer();
}

// entity customer
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCustomer;

    private String titleTypeAccount;
    private String nameCustomer;

    /** RELATIONS **/
    // CUSTOMER - SALES_PERSON
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade={CascadeType.ALL}
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="is_managed",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idCustomer"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idPerson")
    )
    private Collection<Sales_person> salesPersons_BelongTo;
        ...
        ...

// entity sales_person
@Entity
@Table(name="sales_person")
public class Sales_person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long idPerson;

    private String nameSalesPerson;
    private String jobFunction;
    private String titleOrganization;

    @ManyToMany(
        mappedBy="salesPersons_BelongTo"
    )
    private Collection<Customer> customers;
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: It's more helpful to JPA users if you show how you definied the relationship in JPA as well.

Comment: How are your entities annotated? What cascade behavior are you using? Do you use orphanRemoval? A lot of questions that can be answered by showing us the entities code (or DD if you use it)...

Comment: @Piotr Nowicki : I use CascadeType.ALL in Customer Entity but I don't if it is useful to use it in Sales_person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the SalesPerson to be deleted from the database, then you must call em.remove() on the SalesPerson.  Calling merge() is not enough.

Also, if you want the SalesPerson's changes to be merged, you must call merge() on the SalesPerson as well, or set cascade merge on the salesPersons_BelongTo relationship.

Also ensure you are maintaining both sides of the bi-directional relationship, not just one side.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ensure you are maintaining both sides of the bi-directional relationship'? How can I do that? Thank's

Comment: i.e. if you add to one side, you must also add to the other.  Also if the objects are detached and you change both sides, then you must merge both sides.

Comment: It works now, I compared my old collection with the new and used em.remove on Sales_person. Thank's!

Comment: If it works now with comparing collection, do I add to the other side (sales_person.setCustomers(customer))? I mean, Am I obligated? Because it is not important for my application to know the list of customers which are attached to one sales_person.