# JPA - Do I need cascade on many-to-many when using existing entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

Assuming i have a unidirectional many-to-many relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class Document {

    private Integer id;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "document_role", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Document_Id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Role_Id")})
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

Will the following insert into document_role if no Cascade type is defined and assuming no new Role entities will have to be created?

```
Role role1 = em.find(Role.class, 1);
Role role2 = em.find(Role.class, 2);
Role role3 = em.find(Role.class, 3);

Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
roles.add(role1);
roles.add(role2);
roles.add(role3);

Document document = new Document();
document.setRoles(roles);

// Save document, will that save the association?
em.persist(document);
```

What if i also want to update the collection of roles and flush the changes? e.g. remove one role or add another one.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is each table is unique for CRUD.

Example:
If document table has a column id_role which is a foreign key to role table and you update this data, persisting document will update this column because is a property of Document table it will do nothing with Role objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case there is no DocumentRole entity if that's what you're saying, as you might have noticed the association is mapped with a @JoinTable, so i was trying to find some official spec that explains what happens to a many-to-many association table (document_id, role_id) when no cascades are defined.

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis yeah, i read it wrong, im going to edit the answer, but as fas as you ask jpa only update the entity property columns, not related entities if you update Document, only Document is updated, nor Role, because you don't have cascades http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835741/jpa-update-doesnt-work-in-a-many-to-many-relationship